# How do I create a link to a product using just the ID or SKU?

Tags: magento2

I am using the products API (`rest/V1/products/:sku`) and getting back an id for a product.

I'd like to use that to build a URL to the product page - something like

http://my-store.com/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/:id

What is the correct URL?

Note: Direct link to a category works properly:

http://my-store.com/index.php/catalog/category/view/id/:id

One of the `custom_attributes` returned by the products API is `url_key`, but I can't seem to get that to work either:

`[10] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [attribute_code] => url_key
                    [value] => zoltan-gym-tee-l-blue
                )`

http://my-store.com/zoltan-gym-tee-l-blue doesn't work (with or without .html suffix).

I wonder if this is a bug in the products API, because the *real* url key does not include attribute information - i.e., the URL

http://my-store.com/zoltan-gym-tee.html  **does** work.  (But note that this is not the URL key - the url key is "zoltan-gym-tee-l-blue".)

Comment: Should use a user friendly SEO url- url key of product. For example: `http://my-store.com/product-url-key`.

Comment: Tried that too - updated the question to show it.

Comment: How about http://my-store.com/zoltan-gym-tee-l-blue.html

Comment: Nope.  That didn't work either.  Or product/zoltan-gym-tee-l-blue with or without .html.

Comment: Did you try to reindex database?

Comment: Brand new db created from sample data.  But yes, I have rebuilt the indexes.

Comment: Seem that it works with .html?

Comment: This is because your website is enabled `Search Engine Optimization`: Logged in to Magento Admin > STORES > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization > Product URL Suffix.

Comment: It's not that .html is needed - it's that the key, as returned by the API, doesn't work.  See the bottom part of the question and look at the URL that works vs the one that doesn't.  Different keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is,

http://my-store.com/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/:id

is indeed the correct URL. However, this will not work if the product does not have the Visibility setting (in Admin->Products->Catalog->edit product) set so that "Catalog" is included in the value (e.g. "Catalog" or "Catalog,Search").

Note that once this has been done, [PY Yick](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/42656/py-yick)'s comment that you should be able to use use http://my-store.com/zoltan-gym-tee-l-blue.html (i.e. http://my-store.com/product-url-key.html) is correct - provided ".html" is the configured suffix set in Admin->Stores->Configuration->Catalog->SEO->Product URL Suffix.

[The Magento team says](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10276#issuecomment-316124070) they have a backlog item to add URL to the Products API, so hopefully this improvement will be made soon.

Answer (score 0):

This FOSS Module might help.

It overwrites the router and redirects exact SKU matches to the product

https://github.com/karliuka/m2.ProductSkuRedirect

So you would have link like `example.com/1337` if your SKU is 1337

There is also this one which uses a specific route

https://github.com/kodbruket/magento2-gotosku

Here the link is `example.com/gotosku/?sku=1337`